# Compressing and Decompressing on POST and GET requests using lz4 + django + rest_framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, lossless-compression

I am using `django 1.11` + `rest_framework`  trying to implement lossless compression method using [`lz4`](http://github.com/lz4/lz4) `python` library. In a nutshell,I have Implemented a class based view `POST` method that has the compression method defined. I would later want to implement a decompression method when a `GET` request is done. When I try to make a `POST` request I get `TypeErrorr` log:

`a bytes-like object is required, not 'InMemoryUploadedFile'`
I not really familiar with compression of losseless compression some proper direction would be nice. Lastly, is there any other way I would implement compressing and decompressing of files on `POST` and `GET` methods?

My model is as follows:

```
class EmployeeDocument(models.Model):
    """
    Model, Which holds Employee documents uploaded.

    """
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, related_name="employee_docs", null=True, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(
        upload_to='Images/', default='Images/None/No-img.jpg')
    details = models.TextField()
    # url = models.URLField(null=True)
    # path_to_image = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    # upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'DOC - %s' % (self.employee.user.username)
```

Then **Views.py**

```
class EmployeeDocumentPOST(APIView):
    """
      compress Document
    """
    permission_class = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = EmployeeDocumentSerializer

    def compressed_doc(self,document):
        document = lz4.frame.compress(document)
        return document

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        compressd_doc = self.compressed_doc(document)
        employee = Employee.objects.get(id=request.data.pop('employee'))
        detail = request.data.get('detail')
        employee_doc = EmployeeDocument.objects.create(**request.data)

        employee_doc.compressed_doc = compressed_doc
        employee_doc.employee = employee
        employee_doc.detail = detail
        employee_doc.save()

        serializer = EmployeeDocument(employee_doc)
        return Response(serializer.data, status = status, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```